# Reading from a Spotfire Database DataSource without loading it to a table

Tags: sql, ironpython, spotfire

I am working on an IronPython script that pulls some new data from an oracle database, using DatabaseDataSource. I can get the script to pull the data just fine if I just overwrite or append to a table as the output. However, I would like to handle the output of one query in my script, and then use those results to generate another query. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Here's some abbreviated code for what I'm doing now for the first query:

```
PROVIDER = "System.Data.OracleClient"
DATASOURCE = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=TCP)(PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST=host)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid))); UserId=userid;Password=password"

SQL = "SELECT PARM FROM PARAMETERS WHERE ..."

dbsettings = DatabaseDataSourceSettings(PROVIDER, DATASOURCE, SQL)
ds = DatabaseDataSource(dbsettings)

outputTable.ReplaceData(ds)
```

This works, but it just replaces outputTable with the data from the query, obviously. What I'd like to do is read the data I get back in the form of an array. Then, based on the results I will generate another query or set of queries, and eventually I'd merge the data from several of these into one table.